# Selecting some vectors from a matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I am trying to write a code for band matrices that store only the nonzero vectors. For example if I have tridiagonal matrix of size 10, I want to store only the three diagonals as a vectors. n here represent the band size

```
bandmat[mat_, n_] := Module[{k = Dimensions[mat], mt = mat, v},
```

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,

For[j = 1, j <= k - (i - 1), j++,

```
 v[[j]] = Array[mt, {j, j + i - 1}]];];
```

Return[v]]

but it doesn't work. can you tell me please what I did wrong?

Comment: Use a `SparseArray`

Comment: `Table[Diagonal[mat,i],{i,-1,1}]` will return those three diagonals of mat.

Comment: Bill but this is an example, but in genera how to know the domain of i?

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that this was likely a homework question and I try to not do homework for people because learning how to solve a problem on your own is far more important than learning how to ask someone to do the problem for you. A hint: Perhaps you could extract all the diagonals and then choose the ones that satisfy your condition or eliminate those which do not satisfy your condition.